# Segmentation Fault when writing name of file via Termial

Tags: c, string, file, scanf

I have been looking into this for a while and cannot figure it out.
I have the following code and a test.txt file with 10 data points:

```
int main(){
//opening file for reading ("r").
    char *filename;
    printf("Please enter file name: ");
    scanf("%s", filename);
    FILE *file = fopen(filename,"r");


//Counting total number of data points
    int ch; //store character reading
    while(!feof(file)){
      ch = fgetc(file);
      if(ch == '\n'){
        count++;
      }
    }
      fclose(file);
    printf("it is done \n");
    printf("%i", count);
```

If i code it with the filename directly, it works and it successfully counts the 10 data points. However, whenever I try to set it up to scan the filename, once i run it on the terminal and get the message "please enter file name", I write it in, and I always just end up getting "segmentation fault". What am i doing wrong, please help.

Comment: Do you have a "C" or "C++" question? I think "C", if so remove "C++" tag, C++ is a different language (using std::string for strings not char*, std::ifstream instead of FILE*, etc...).

Comment: What I remember from "C". It seems you have not allocated any memory for your filename. So you are reading your filename into random memory. Use `char[some contant buffer size]`

Comment: Note: `while(!feof(file)){  ch = fgetc(file);` is wrong and the last character you'll read will be `EOF`. Change it to `while((ch = fgetc(file) != EOF) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the other answerer said, it's a size problem, but you can also set the filename buffer to NULL:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void read_line_stdin(const char* message, char **buffer) {
  printf("%s", message);
  size_t len;
  int read = getline(buffer, &len, stdin)
  if (read == -1)
    printf("No line read...\n");
}

int main() {
  char *filename = NULL;
  read_line_input("Input filename > ", &filename);
  
  ...
  
  free(filename); // FREE the memory!
}
```

Edit:

This answer was not generated with ChatGPT :)

Comment: Presumably this is using [POSIX `getline`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html), which should be noted as it is not strictly portable (the question does not specify a platform).

Answer (score 1):

```
    char *filename;
    printf("Please enter file name: ");
    scanf("%s", filename);
    FILE *file = fopen(filename,"r");
```

**You cannot use an uninitialized pointer (`filename`), it must point somewhere with enough data to hold the file name.**  It's better to use an array, as in:

```
    char filename[256];
    printf("Please enter file name: ");
    scanf("%.255s", filename);
    FILE *file = fopen(filename,"r");
```

(I've added `.255` to indicate scanf that you are about to read text for upto 256 characters)  or you can even:

```
    char filename[256];
    printf("Please enter file name: ");
    scanf("%.*s", (sizeof filename) - 1, filename);
    FILE *file = fopen(filename,"r");
```

(I've used an uneeded pair of parenthesis around `sizeof filename` to indicate that the parameter value is one less (to allow space for the end of string null character, so the maximum string length is used in only one place , making more robust piece of code)

Read the man page of scanf(3) for more details on format specifiers.

Answer (score 0):

This diagnosis is generated with the help of ChatGPT. I did modify the answer to fit into your question.
First, you didn't declare the `count` variable used to increment in your while loop.
Second, before you use 'scanf' function, you need to allocate memory for the `filename` pointer

Here's a modified version of your code:

#include <stdio.h>

````
int main() {
    char filename[100]; // Allocate memory for the filename
    int count = 0; // Initialize count to zero

    printf("Please enter file name: ");
    scanf("%s", filename);

    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to open the file.\n");
        return 1; // Exit with an error code
    }

    int ch; // Store character reading
    while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
        if (ch == '\n') {
            count++;
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
    printf("Number of lines in the file: %d\n", count);

    return 0; // Exit with success code
}
```
````

In this code:

1. `filename` was declared with a fixed size (max of 100 chars) to store the file name.
2. Error-checking cases were added (File== NULL) to ensure the file can be opened successfully.
3. `Count` was declared and initialized to zero.
4. The `while` loop was modified to read characters until the end of the file (`EOF`).

This code should correctly count the number of lines in the specified text file. Ensure to include error handling to handle cases where the file might not exist or cannot be opened.

Comment: Did you use chatGPT to generate this answer?

Comment: FYI [Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)